# An equivalent of "Your Honor" for a Congresswoman?

Tags: american-english

I am writing to a Congresswoman and would like to use a honorific similar to "Your honor." I think 'your honor' is only used in judiciary vocabulary.

Are honorifics used in formal American English?

Comment: You might need to give some details of the person's role or rank if you want some kind of official form of address. What reasearch have you done, what conclusions reached etc?

Comment: I am writing to a Congresswoman and am not sure how to mention her in middle of my letter.

Comment: Agree with @ralph.m, "your honor" is usually used with members of the judiciary and would be out of place otherwise, but there are equivalents for other officials.   Many/most letter greetings are actually Mr./Madam <Title>, e.g. Mr. Secretary, Madam Ambassador.   I've seen longer verisons like The Honorable John Doe, Secretary of State, or whatever.

Comment: I agree with you. For the beginning of letter these are fine. I am curious about mentioning the person in the middle to bring her attention and emphasis. Maybe I am not thinking English. In my language this is possible.

Comment: There are specific protocols and traditions for each office or rank; in conversation you would greet them as *Congressman/ Congresswoman X* or *Representative X* , but a letter would be addressed to *The Honorable X*, and the salutation on the letter would traditionally be *Mr./Ms./Dr. X* (or their military rank). The level of respect accorded the official is irrelevant, and in fact, displays of obsequiousness or flattery can annoy or even offend people.

Comment: Dear Congresswoman Doe,

Comment: *Your honor* is for the judiciary, regardless male, female or born-in-between. For an elected person, the honorific pattern is more towards, * honourable Ms Pennyfarthing*. e.g. "Let us welcome our honorable Congresswoman MsPennyfarthing", or "Dear honourable Ms Pennyfarthing ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a US Congresswoman named Jane Doe, there are a few options.

- Congresswoman Doe
- Representative Doe
- Ms. Doe
- The Honorable Jane Doe

If in the middle of your letter you want to reference them again by name, any of the first 3 would work.  Or you could just say 'congresswoman'.

[House.gov reference](http://www.house.gov/representatives/find/#properform)

[Emily Post suggestions](http://emilypost.com/advice/official-forms-of-address/)

Comment: Congresswoman Doe is a dragon. Just saying.

Comment: Hmm, curious about the down vote.  Does someone disagree?

Comment: Now why would anyone downvote this? ... You brilliant people you ...

Comment: I'm giving it a +1 to cancel out the downvote. Some people are just too brilliant for their own good.

Comment: @Ricky Agreed, since he gave a reference straight from the horse's mouth.  +.707

Answer (score 0):

@Dusty's answer is explicit and to the point. My two cents:

In the second half of the 18th Century an event occurred known today as the American Revolution. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Revolution).

Many interesting things happened, including, but hardly limited to, the signing of the Declaration of Independence, penned by Thomas Jefferson, edited by his colleagues (they struck out the part in which Mr. Jefferson tried to blame slavery on George III), and depicted in this highly romanticized painting by John Trumbull:

[image: deadrat, Esq., overseeing downvotes on Meta]

Because it was a British tradition to use titles and honorifics, the patriotic Americans who came into power at that point made it their business to eschew those, establishing a new, American, tradition. Some Americans - such as the Quakers - were allergic to honorifics even before that.

Comment: The Jeffersonian democrats were rather more allergic than the Federalists. Washington himself is said to have favored ""His High Mightiness, the President of the United States of America, and Protector of their Liberties," but in any case I don't see a connection to the original question.

Comment: The timeline indicates that this answer was posted after the question was edited. The acceptance of an answer indicates that the OP is happy with the edited question. Since the edit was to replace "highly respected official" with something more specific, this answer doesn't answer the question -- it doesn't even address how to refer to a "highly respected official" -- it's a commentary on post-revolutionary titles.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I'm not sure, let me take a look ... ah, yes. There is something in the body of the question post about "formal American English." Which, of course, is neither here nor there.